# Эффект автодополнения

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С input такое сделать невозможно, поэтому будем использовать `div` с атрибутом `contenteditable="true"`

Есть форма ввода. Пользователь вводит в неё текст и автоматически производится поиск по базе данных.
Как полученный результат из БД сделать в виде некого `placeholder`, который недоступен пользователю, а по нажатию на пробел заменить введённый результат на результат из этого `placeholder`?

Answer (score 1):

С инпутом можно как-то так:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector("label").dataset.hint = e.target.value + "ква"
})
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  text-align: start;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label::before {
  content: attr(data-hint);
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 0;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<label><input autofocus></label>
```